# how to make button placed on top of UICollectionView react to the tap?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

UICollectionView which behaves as a gallery

```
gallery.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator  = false
gallery.isPagingEnabled = true
```

is placed inside UIView container and on this container, custom button (favorite image button) is added:

[image]

```
galleryContainer.addSubview(gallery)
galleryContainer.addSubview(pageControl)

...

galleryContainer.addSubview(favBtn)
favBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: galleryContainer.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
favBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: galleryContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
favBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
favBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

The problem is that the favorite button does not react on the tap, why, and how can this be fixed? I tried `favBtn.becomeFirstResponder()` but without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the issue was that button overlapped the top navigation bar which had `isTranslucent = true` property. Once I managed to move the button beyond the navigation bar it became active.

Answer (score 2):

Bring your button to the front and enable interact

```
galleryContainer.bringSubview(toFront: favBtn)
favBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Not only the `favBtn` should be enabled for user interaction, but also the container, in this scenario `galleryContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`